# MONTHS_BETWEEN in Oracle.. Exact logic of calculation

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-date-functions

What is the exact logic behind Oracle's months_between function?
I tried this query:

```
SELECT D1, 
       D2, 
       MONTHS_BETWEEN (D1, D2) DIFF,
       (D1-D2)/31 MANUAL_CALC1,
       (D1-D2)/30 MANUAL_CALC2,
       (D1-D2)/29 MANUAL_CALC3,
       (D1-D2)/28 MANUAL_CALC4
FROM (SELECT TO_DATE('07-03-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY') D1, 
             TO_DATE('04-02-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY') D2
        FROM DUAL);
```

And got result as:
DIFF: 1.09
MANUAL_CALC1: 1
MANUAL_CALC2: 1.03
MANUAL_CALC3: 1.06
MANUAL_CALC4: 1.10

I am converting an Oracle package into a Java program and I need to generate exact same results. But just this one function (months_between) is spoiling the party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`4th of Feb` to `4th of March` is `1` Month..

Remaining is *3* days to `7th of March`.. So `3/31` (always 31 as benchmark) = `.09` Months

So the answer is total of `1+ 0.09 = 1.09`

THe Formula goes like,

```
FLOOR(ABS(MONTHS_BETWEEN(D1,D2))) + /* The Actual Month difference, as whole number */
 (TO_CHAR(D1,'DD') - TO_CHAR(D2,'DD'))/31 /* Remaining Days / 31)*/
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/36073)

Comment: Per my testing, the divisor is always 31 - the documentation also says this. Also, did you just explain months_between function using months_between? ;-)

Comment: Ha Ha.. I thought the whole number calculation is simple with it ;)

Comment: Bingo! The correct thought. But just one thing. The divisor is 31 days in all cases. Not the number of days of D1. I tried: TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(D1, 'MM')) - TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(D2, 'MM')) + (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(D1, 'DD')) - TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(D2, 'DD')))/31 with multiple dates and all gave me exact result as Oracle's months_between. Thanks! Please correct your answer and then I will accept it.

Comment: @toddlermenot: haha.. yeah I am :) Maheswaran: One more thing. FLOOR will fail you when it comes to the negative differences. FLOOR(-5.9) is -6 and not -5. Try D1 "02-01-2014" and D2 "03-02-2014". So I would go with the the code I commented. If you could correct your answer, it will help somebody else.

Comment: And I was partially incorrect with my explanation. I would eaither edit my answer with a test case, or remove it. Apologies, It's been so many years with Oracle, now I feel ashamed to not understand myself. Sorry again. I learnt something new today!

Comment: @GireeshPuthumana I agree with the floor thing.. And Lalit.. Nothing to apologise, it is collective learning..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    a.dt_base,
    a.dt,
    a.months,
    a.days,
    a.mms,
    a.my_months,
    a.bias,
    a.day_part,
    a.my_add_months
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            a.dt_base,
            a.dt,
            a.months,
            a.days,
            a.mms,
            a.my_months,
            31 - TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(a.dt_base,TRUNC(a.months))),'dd')) bias,
            ((a.months - TRUNC(a.months)) * 31) day_part,
            CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(a.dt_base,TRUNC(a.months)),'yyyymm') != TO_CHAR((ADD_MONTHS(a.dt_base,TRUNC(a.months)) + ((a.months - TRUNC(a.months)) * 31)),'yyyymm') THEN
                ADD_MONTHS(a.dt_base,TRUNC(a.months)) + ((a.months - TRUNC(a.months)) * 31) - (31 - TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(a.dt_base,TRUNC(a.months))),'dd')))
            ELSE 
                ADD_MONTHS(a.dt_base,TRUNC(a.months)) + ((a.months - TRUNC(a.months)) * 31)
            END my_add_months
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    a.dt_base,
                    a.dt,
                    a.months,
                    a.days,
                    a.mms,
                    mms + days / 31 my_months
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            a.dt_base,
                            a.dt,
                            a.months,
                            CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(a.dt_base,'dd') > to_char(a.dt,'dd') THEN
                                31 - TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(a.dt_base,'dd')) + TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(a.dt,'dd'))
                            ELSE
                                TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(a.dt,'dd')) - TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(a.dt_base,'dd'))
                            END days
                            , CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(a.dt_base,'dd') > TO_CHAR(a.dt,'dd') THEN
                                ( TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(a.dt,'yyyy')) * 12 + TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(a.dt,'mm')) )
                                -
                                ( TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(a.dt_base,'yyyy')) * 12 + TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(a.dt_base,'mm')) )
                                - 1
                            ELSE
                                ( TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(a.dt,'yyyy')) * 12 + TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(a.dt,'mm')) )
                                -
                                ( TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(a.dt_base,'yyyy')) * 12 + TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(a.dt_base,'mm')) )
                            END mms
                        FROM
                            (
                                SELECT
                                    dt_base,
                                    dt,
                                    MONTHS_BETWEEN(dt,dt_base) months
                                FROM
                                    (
                                        SELECT
                                            TRUNC(sysdate,'dd') dt_base,
                                            TRUNC(sysdate,'dd') + level - 1 dt
                                        FROM    dual
                                        CONNECT BY level < 36500
                                    ) a
                            ) a
                    )a
            ) a
    ) a
WHERE   a.dt != a.my_add_months
```

Comment: an explanantion of whatever you are doing wil help